# Looping through multiple tables in SQLite query for HTML5 - Asynchronous timing

Tags: sql, html, sqlite, asynchronous

I have a SQLite query to pull orders from an ORDERS table in a database:

```
        qry.executeSql("SELECT o.ID AS orderIDx, o.token AS orderTokenx, r.retailerName AS retailerNamex FROM orders AS o LEFT JOIN retailers AS r ON r.token = o.retailerID  ", [], function(tx, results){
            //query was a success
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
                var orderID = results.rows.item(i).orderIDx;
                var orderToken = results.rows.item(i).orderTokenx;
                var retailerName = results.rows.item(i).retailerNamex;
                //create container for order and populate it with orderItems in the below query                     
                qry.executeSql("SELECT * FROM orderItems WHERE orderID =  '"+orderToken+"' ", [], function(tx1, results1){

                    var len1 = results1.rows.length;
                    for (var i1=0; i1<len1; i1++){          
                        $('.orderItem.'+orderID+' p').append(results1.rows.item(i1).productName);                       
                    }
                });
            }               
        });
```

This is my query but with a lot of clutter taken out, ive left the essentials.

So I am trying to loop through the orders table and show order specific info in one section, and within that as a drop down I widh to displat each order item. So within the order loop I am using that ID to call orderItems etc... but it is only appending the results of the orderItem query in the last container.

I hink this is because the query is Asynchronous, but I am unsure how to popupulate the orderItem container before the next loop for the order query is carried out :/

I am struggling to do the same thing with Asynchronmous jQuery AJAX stuff.. so if this is linked then an explanation would be great.

Also, I was going to use a JOIN to join the order and orerItems tables in the outer query, but was then unsure about how to loop through the items as well as the orders within 1 loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the problem seems to be the `orderID` variable which changes before the orderItems get appended.

I think it will help if you would change last for loop into

```
var len1 = results1.rows.length;
var order_id = results1.rows.item(0).orderID;
for (var i1=0; i1<len1; i1++){          
    $('.orderItem.'+order_id+' p').append(results1.rows.item(i1).productName);                       
}
```

In this case you won't be using the changed variable anymore.

Comment: Ha ok thanks. I probably made that more complicated than it needed to be